# EF Core one-to-one relationship swapping references issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, one-to-one

I have two entities

```
public class Student {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public StudentAddress Address { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class StudentAddress {
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

basically one-to-one relationship

I've got such code

```
var students = await context.Students.Include(s => s.Address).ToListAsync();

var student1 = students[0];
var student2 = students[1];

var st1Addr = student1.Address;
var st2Addr = student2.Address;

student1.Address = st2Addr;
student2.Address = st1Addr;

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When EF saves changes one of the student address records gets deleted from DB.

I need to change references to student addresses. How can I achieve this with EF core?

Comment: Could you share the underlying data of the two records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a 1-1 relationship, as soon as you set

```
 student1.Address = st2Addr;
```

student1's old address must be deleted, as it would violate the unique constraint on SudentAddress.StudentId.  And it's not just a limitation in the change tracker. 
SaveChanges will not be able to run

```
UPDATE StudentAddress set StudentId = @StudentId where StudentAddressID = @Id
```

without first deleting the other row, as it would violate the unique constraint.  And constraints are generally enforced for each DML statement, not deferred until the transaction is committed.  You could do this in SQL with a single update statement, eg

```
update SudentAddress set StudentID = case when studentId = 1 then 2 else 1 end
where StudentId in (1,2)
```

If you explicitly set the deleted address back to modified

```
db.Entry(st1Addr).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You'll see SaveChanges fail because it can't come up with a sequence of changes that leaves the database in the desired state.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to save changes because a
>   circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved

So just modifying the SudentAddress.StudentId directly won't help here.

I think the only way do do this through the change tracker is to make copies of the StudentAddress entities.  Then both old ones will be deleted and the new ones inserted.